# how to send response directly from worker to client

Tags: nginx

When Nginx is used as a reverse proxy so that the client connects to Nginx and Nginx load balances or otherwise redirects the request to a backend worker via CGI etc... what is it called and how is it implemented when the worker responds directly to the client bypassing Nginx?

The source of my question is from two places. a) erlangonxen uses Nginx and a "spawner" app to launch a huge volume of instant-on workers. However, the response still passes through the spawner (an expensive step); b) I recently scanned an article that described this solution but I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 0):

You got your jargon mixed I believe, so I'm going to ignore the proxy bit and assume this is about CGI. In that case you should be looking for fast CGI solutions. Nginx has support for fast CGI built in.

This spawner as you call it, is meant to provide concurrency, so that multiple CGI requests can be handled in parallel, without having to spawn an interpreter for each request. Instead the workers get spawned and ideally live forever.

If the selection of an available worker really is a performance bottleneck, then the implementation of this fast CGI daemon is severely lacking and you should look for a better solution. Worker selection should be a fraction of the time of the workers job.

Comment: The intent is for the Spaner to create the workers ad hoc. Each worker performance single task Or maintain a single session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a jargon thing.  The good news (for me anyway) is that I had read the articles and seen the diagrams... I just could not remember where. So reverse proxy not withstanding... I was looking for a "direct server request" ([DSR](https://splash.riverbed.com/docs/DOC-1550)) and the [spawner](https://github.com/maximk/spawnpool) from the erlangonxen project.

I'm not certain whether ot not these two technologies are going to work together.  The DSR seems to have fallen out of favor and I'll probably not use it al all although in the given architecture it would seem to make sense to try. a) limits the total number of trips and sockets; b) really allows for some functions like gzip to be distributed nicely

Anyway, "found it".

Comment: My mistake. Direct server response.